# Custom pop animation to a UICollectionViewController doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uianimation, custom-transition

I have a collection view called ProfileCollectionViewController for collection of images.
When clicked on an image it presents a HorizontalProfileViewController which displays images in full screen.
When back button is pressed on HorizontalProfileViewController I want the full screen image to animate back to a thumbnail in ProfileViewController. I pass the selected index path from ProfileViewController as initialIndexPath to HorizontalProfileViewController so that the position of thumbnail is known. Below is my transition animation code

```
import UIKit

class SEHorizontalFeedToProfile: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.2
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        if let profileVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as? SEProfileGridViewController, horizontalFeedVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as? SEProfileHorizontalViewController, containerView = transitionContext.containerView() {
            let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)
            profileVC.collectionView?.reloadData()
            if let indexPath = horizontalFeedVC.initialIndexPath {
                let cell = profileVC.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                print(indexPath)
                let imageSnapshot = horizontalFeedVC.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
                let snapshotFrame = containerView.convertRect(horizontalFeedVC.view.frame, fromView: horizontalFeedVC.view)
                imageSnapshot.frame = snapshotFrame
                horizontalFeedVC.view.hidden = true

                profileVC.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(profileVC)
                containerView.insertSubview(profileVC.view, belowSubview: horizontalFeedVC.view)
                containerView.addSubview(imageSnapshot)

                UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
                    var cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    if let theFrame = cell?.frame {
                        cellFrame = theFrame
                    }
                    let frame = containerView.convertRect(cellFrame, fromView: profileVC.collectionView)
                    imageSnapshot.frame = frame
                    }, completion: { (succeed) in
                        if succeed {
                            horizontalFeedVC.view.hidden = false
                            //                                cell.contentView.hidden = false
                            imageSnapshot.removeFromSuperview()
                            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
                        }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I put breakpoints and found out that in the code

```
let cell = profileVC.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

the cell is nil. I don't understand why it would be nil. Please help me. I thank you in advance.

The profileVC is a subclass of UICollectionViewController

PS: Please check out the following project that does exactly the same thing without any issues. I tried to mimic it but it doesn't work on mine.
https://github.com/PeteC/InteractiveViewControllerTransitions

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range. Is your question why is my cell not visible?

Comment: My question is why is a cell of a toViewController nil in an pop animation? How can I fix it?

Comment: You may want to size and add the profileVC.view to the container _before_ you reload the collection view

Comment: The cell is not visible so `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is returning nil https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:. One solution is to pass the frame of collection view cell rather than the index path. I have a working sample project if you need some code, but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: That will not work for me because on the full screen image view the user can swipe left and right to view other images. The initialIndexPath is updated accordingly.

Comment: @Subash: can you post your whole code so that debug in detail.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments on the question, the cell is set to nil because the cell is not visible. Since your HorizontalProfileViewController allows scrolling to other pictures it is possible to scroll to an image that has not yet had a UICollectionViewCell created for it in your ProfileCollectionViewController.

You can remedy this by scrolling to where the current image should be on the UICollectionView. You say that `initialIndexPath` is initially the indexPath of the image that was first selected. Assuming you update that as the user scrolls to different images so that it still accurately represents the on screen image's indexPath, we can use that to force the UICollectionView to scroll to the current cell if necessary.

With a few tweaks to your code this should give you the desired effect:

```
import UIKit    

class SEHorizontalFeedToProfile: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.2
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    if let profileVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) as? SEProfileGridViewController, horizontalFeedVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as? SEProfileHorizontalViewController, containerView = transitionContext.containerView() {
        let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)
        //profileVC.collectionView?.reloadData()  //Remove this

        if let indexPath = horizontalFeedVC.initialIndexPath {
            var cell = profileVC.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) //make cell a var so it can be reassigned if necessary
            print(indexPath)

            if cell == nil{  //This if block is added. Again it is crucial that initialIndexPath was updated as the user scrolled.
                profileVC.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(horizontalFeedVC.initialIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically, animated: false)
                profileVC.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded() //This is necessary to force the collectionView to layout any necessary new cells after scrolling
                cell = profileVC.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            }
            let imageSnapshot = horizontalFeedVC.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
            let snapshotFrame = containerView.convertRect(horizontalFeedVC.view.frame, fromView: horizontalFeedVC.view)
            imageSnapshot.frame = snapshotFrame
            horizontalFeedVC.view.hidden = true

            profileVC.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(profileVC)
            containerView.insertSubview(profileVC.view, belowSubview: horizontalFeedVC.view)
            containerView.addSubview(imageSnapshot)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
                var cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                if let theFrame = cell?.frame {
                    cellFrame = theFrame
                }
                let frame = containerView.convertRect(cellFrame, fromView: profileVC.collectionView)
                imageSnapshot.frame = frame
                }, completion: { (succeed) in
                    if succeed {
                        horizontalFeedVC.view.hidden = false
                        //                                cell.contentView.hidden = false
                        imageSnapshot.removeFromSuperview()
                        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now if the current UICollectionViewCell is not yet created it:

1. Scrolls so the indexPath of the cell is centered on the view
2. Forces the UICollectionView to layout its subviews which creates any UITableViewCells that are necessary
3. Asks for the UITableViewCell again, but this time it should not be nil